# Error while installing Typescript plugin in Brackets

Tags: typescript, adobe-brackets

[plugin for typescript](https://github.com/fdecampredon/brackets-typescript)

> I dont have any idea about,why this internal error occurs. I'm using a windows 7 32bit system.

[image: Showing internal error]

Answer (score 1):

The TypeScript plugin for Brackets (from Francois de Campredon) has not been updated for quite a while.  Unfortunately, the version of TypeScript that this plugin uses is around v1.4, and will therefore show up errors when using the later versions of TypeScript.

You would be better off using Visual Studio Code as an editor.

That said, you may have better results if you download the .zip file for this plugin, and then install locally.

Comment: I tried to install it locally,still same error is showing up.

Comment: Can you suggest any other text editor with good typescript support?

Comment: Visual Studio Code.